# Maven Snapshot in pom.xml

Tags: maven

There are a easy way to make Maven put "-SNAPSHOT" on my versions? We have a project with many POMs.

We usualy create branchs from TAGs that haven't SNAPSHOTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Use the [release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html):</del>

<del>`mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`</del>

You can use the [versions-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html) to do that:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Alternatively, you could use `release:branch` to even create the branch as well (provided the scm settings in your pom are correct):

```
(check out tag)
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -DreleaseVersion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Yes, the property is named **releaseVersion**, although it is really the version for the branch. (see: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html for details)

Comment: release:update-versions fails: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4:update-versions (default-cli) on project catalog: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Define new property in parent pom.xml:

```
<properties>
   <myprojectversion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myprojectversion>
</properties>
```

and use it whenever needed: `${myprojectversion}`.

If this solution is too rough. Consider to define more properties for minor, major, postfix etc. parts of intended version code.